# Azure web Application CodeFirst Error

Tags: c#, mysql, azure

I'm creating a Web Application in visual studio for an application.

On localhost, its working smooth, the problem comes when I port it to azure.

http://infolab.azurewebsites.net/api/users/getuserlist

This is the error I get in every single method of the API.

I've created a database in MySQL with MySql Workbench and used entityframework to implement his usage.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Did you use EF Migrations? Do you use Database First or Code First? How did you deploy the db?

Comment: Hmm im not sure what is EF migrations. About DB first or code first, not sure which I should use. And the db was deployed using Mysql workbench. Though i'm kinda lost since it's the first time doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having what sounds like the same issue (Can't see the error on the link but my error was in regards to CODEFIRST/Entity issue), couldn't find answers anywhere that would work for me. After a day of trial and head slapping I came across a connection strings setting on Azure that I'd completely forgot I had set up.
Home > App Services > {YOUR APP} > Configuration

At the bottom of the page you'll find Connection Strings . If it is the same problem I was having you'll have at least one in the listings. This setting was overriding my connection strings in code and it was written in a code first format (no meta tag). I simply deleted the entry in Azure then re-published my code. Worked fine after that.

[Connection String Section in Azure  -> APP -> Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yAoa.jpg)

Hope that helps somebody.